# How to convert Expansion File assets Resources (InputStreams ) TO Drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

Well i am working on Expansion Files. I am getting the file and now i am trying to access the content of expansion file which is a zip file . I got expansion file entries in "expansionFile". Now i am getting input stream from expansion file.

**Here is the look of my exapnsion file:**

`main.1.com.test.downloader.obb`
inside it there is assets folder and inside assets folder there are images.

**Here is my code:**

```
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("assets/");
Log.i("File",""+fileStream.toString());
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(fileStream, "abacus.jpg");
```

I am getting error on Drawable line. I think i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After search i came to know that here is the solution:

```
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("assets/"+imageName);
  Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(fileStream, null);
  _imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```